# Отступ bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, отступы

Ребят, Нужна помощь, как изменить отступы у тех элементов, которые я выделил на скрине?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код: http://www.bootply.com/OJG5rU1QBi#

```js
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel,
.item,
.active {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* faster sliding speed */

.carousel-inner > .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out left;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out left;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out left;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out left;
}
/* keep full widget on smaller screens */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container fill">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="active item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/1024x700/449955/FFF');">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/1024x700');">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/1024x700/CC1111/FFF');">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-center">
      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```